# how to manage between root and mnt folder structure on tablets

Tags: android, tabs, android-sdcard

Working on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 with external storage.

I have a "xyz" folder on sdcard.

But when I am trying to get it through code like

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/xyz/";
```

doesn't work as on tab file path becomes as

```
/Root/sdcard/xyz.
```

other than tab path is something like. "/mnt/sdcard/xyz"

How to deal with this.

Any help will be regretted.

Answer (score 0):

In my Samsung galaxy tab i used this:

```
String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
file = new File( root_sd + "/external_sd" ) ; 
//Now file points to my external sdcard
```

In the above case i think you need to do this:

```
String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
file = new File( root_sd + "/external_sd/xyz/" ) ;
```

`Note`: If the above code doesn't work, then it means you have given a name to your sdcard. Eg. If i have named my external sdcard as rockStar, the below is the code:

```
String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
file = new File( root_sd + "/rockStar/xyz/" ) ;
```